# Single Sign-On with oAuth2 or Shared Session

Tags: session, oauth, oauth-2.0, openid, single-sign-on

I have three client-facing web applications all on different subdomains (one of these web applications actually has 700+ different subdomains that are changing all the time).  I've written an oAuth server that I was going to use to allow users to login to each of these systems; this works, but I've begun running into differences between what's happening and what I would like the behavior to actually be when writing the logout code.

Some of my requirements for single sign-on are:

- If logged in on one system, you are logged in on all systems (obviously).
- If logging out of one system, you are logged out of all systems.  Even across subdomains.
- If you are logged in on two different machines, for example -- a cellphone and a desktop.  When logging out on your cellphone, do NOT logout on your desktop.

We already have written the oAuth provider and we'll be using it for projects not coupled to our domain (API's, etc.), but I'm not entirely convinced that oAuth is the best solution to use to meet the requirements outlined above.  I'm thinking that maybe a shared session would be better.  The shared session idea would involve a cookie stored on the main domain that has information about the currently logged-in user.

What are the pros and cons of either approach?  Are there other approaches you might take?  Are there security risks to consider?  Concurrency and scalability considerations?  Please help!

Answer (score 0):

I would have taken oauth route with a variance.

1. **Oauth** :

The approach I would prefer is - access token issued at a device level (User- Application/Device) . 
Ie there will be a process for registering your device and granting access for it.
This will result in the generation of an access token specific to the device and stored in it as the case may be. (For eg:- for mobile you may need a longer expiry access token and webpage a lesser duration one).
This way you can decouple the login/log-out across devices.

However the con of this approach is:

1. More complicated implementation, as it involves device registration
2. Tracking the action of each user will be difficult as you have two or more access token tied to a user.

Pros :

- This is a fairly standard way
- The Con 2 can be worked around (Adding access token attributes etc).

---

2. **Session based SSO management**

Pros :

- Simpler than OAuth

Cons :

- Security constraints around -session/cookie handling
- Extendability at later point to add more use-cases is limited